# Removing duplicate strings in bash

Tags: bash

How can I remove strings based on a string in the proceeding line? For instance I have the following:

```
This text is unique
TEXT A    
This is also unique
TEXT A    
Completely unique text here
TEXT B    
Some more unique text
TEXT C
```

I want to be able to output the following:

```
This is also unique
Completely unique text here
Some more unique text
```

Hopefully from that it makes sense that what I want to do is use the text on the `n+1th` line to determine uniqueness, and print the text on the `nth` line.

The choice of which `TEXT A` is determined purely by the order that it is fed into the command.

I've achieved something similar to this when I only needed to remove duplicate IP addresses using `sort -u` as so: `echo "$IP_ADDRESSES" | sort -u`.

Comment: Why removing `TEXT B`? It seems unique for me in your example.

Comment: @DevilaN, eh? The strings come *before* the labels, so what the sample shows removed is the second `TEXT A`.

Comment: @CircularRecursion ...I just noticed that you want `This is also unique`, not `This text is unique`, to be the first line. That's doable, but requires some tradeoffs. Do you care about retaining ordering? Switching to `tac` to process lines in reverse order is the easiest approach, though doing that while emitting the first line first would mean *two* `tac`s, one at the beginning of your pipeline and another at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate tool for using arbitrary strings as keys with amortized-constant-time lookup (so you can track which ones you've seen before) is an associative array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0 required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A seen_labels=( )  # initialize an empty associative array
while IFS= read -r str && IFS= read -r label; do # read string/label pair
  [[ ${seen_labels[$label]} ]] && continue       # skip pair if label prev. seen
  seen_labels[$label]=1                          # flag label as seen
  printf '%s\n' "$str"                           # print string
done
```

See this in operation at https://ideone.com/zubTWi